# How are chained assignments in java defined? Is there a difference between value and reference types?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

How are chained assignments in java defined, considering following points:

- Is there a difference between chained assignment and chained declaration?
- Is there a way for reference types to repeat the statement instead of passing the reference?

E.g.

```
Integer a, b = new Integer(4);
```

In [JLS 15.26 Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html) it says

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an assignment expression is not itself a variable.

So `a == b` should be true.

Is there a way to achieve

```
Integer a = new Integer(4)
Integer b = new Integer(4)
```

in one line so that
`a != b`, since `a` and `b` are different objects.

**Additional Info**

The question is already answered, but I felt it was not clear enough, so here some code
to clarify it.

```
Integer a = null, b = null, c = null;
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c); // null null null
a = b = c = new Integer(5); // <-- chained assignment
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c); // 5 5 5
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true
System.out.println(b.equals(c)); // true
System.out.println(a == b); // true
System.out.println(b == c); // true
```

Comment: Generally Integers from -128 to 127 are cached in memory so you will never get a != b in your example, but I get your point.

Comment: @Pescis `a != b` as in reference equality, not value equality.

Comment: I mixed in a mistake `Integer a, b = new Integer(4);` leaves `a` `null`

Comment: @Pescis: `new Integer` will *always* return a reference to a new object. This isn't boxing or using `Integer.valueOf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
Integer a = new Integer(4), b = new Integer(4);
```

Personally I think that's less readable than using two separate declarations though, and there's no way of doing it without either repeating the `new Integer(4)` or extracting that to some other method which you then call twice.

Comment: Thought maybe there was a way, where I don't have to repeat the constructor call. Thx!